# How to add 2014 in my date function - PHP?

Tags: php, date

I currently found this date function a while back that works fine ( can't remember where i found it) but it displays all days, months and years from 2013. The problem is now I need people to be able to select 2014 from the drop down as well. Not really sure what I should edit to add this.

Thanks for any help... the code:

```
function date_dropdown($year_limit = 0){

   $daynow = date("d");
   $monthnowtxt = date('F');
   $monthnow = date('m');
   $yearnow = date("20y");

   $html_output = '<div id="date_select" >'."\n";
   $html_output .= '<label for="date_day">Date of Longplay</label>'."\n";

    /*days*/
   $html_output .= '<select name="date_day" id="day_select"><option  ="selected" value="' . $daynow . '">' . $daynow . '</option>'."\n";
   for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
       $html_output .= '<option>' . $day . '</option>'."\n";
   }
  $html_output .= '</select>'."\n";

    /*months*/
  $html_output .= '<select name="date_month" id="month_select" ><option selected="selected" value="' . $monthnow . '">' . $monthnowtxt . '</option>'."\n";
  $months = array("", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
  for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
      $html_output .= '               <option value="' . $month . '">' . $months[$month] . '</option>'."\n";
   } 
   $html_output .= '</select>'."\n";

   /*years*/
   $html_output .= '<select name="date_year" id="year_select"><option ="selected" value="' . $yearnow . '">' . $yearnow . '</option>'."\n";
   for ($year = 1900; $year <= (date("Y") - $year_limit); $year++) {
           $html_output .= '               <option>' . $year . '</option>'."\n";
   }
   $html_output .= '</select>'."\n";

   $html_output .= '</div>'."\n";
   return $html_output;
  }
```

Comment: *"Not really sure what I should edit to add this."* Well, I see a `for` loop on the variable `$year` that prints `<option>` tags. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: Nowdays, just ignore pretty HTML generation if you build it like this and concentrate more on readable backend code. There are plenty pretty printers out there if someone actually cares to read the generated source (including you). Or better yet, use templates or something else than straight up string concatenation for HTML. My 2c.

Comment: @plain-jane: your edits to this code would be good if it was your own code - I agree the spacing is unnecessary. But it's a good idea to preserve code in mostly its natural state, otherwise there's a danger that something critical to the question is lost. (This has now been approved, so no worries in this case - just a suggestion for future edits).

Comment: @halfer: yes, i understand we should `respect the author` but just to reduce the horizontal scroll and better readability i edited it, no other intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bit you need to change

```
for ($year = 1900; $year <= (date("Y") - $year_limit); $year++)
```

`date('Y')` will return 2013

`date('Y')+1` will return 2014

```
for ($year = 1900; $year <= ((date("Y")+1) - $year_limit); $year++)
```

I have to say I don't like the function you included and there are probably cleaner more flexible ways to do what it does.

Comment: Thanks allen213.. didnt realise it was that simple. real quick help. Many thanks

Comment: Adams answer is simpler

Comment: ha, i answered the phone during writing my answer....you beat me to it :( lol

Comment: @user1936399 - why you do not use my solution? There is no need to modify the function code :)

Comment: For what its worth @Adam I'd use yours

Answer (score 3):

this method call gives you 2014:

```
date_dropdown(-1);
```

Comment: true enough, missed that

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
for ($year = 1900; $year <= (date("Y") - $year_limit); $year++)
```

to this

```
for ($year = 1900; $year <= ((date("Y")+1) - $year_limit); $year++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `for` loop

```
for ($year = 1900; $year <= (date("Y") - $year_limit); $year++)
```

to

```
for ($year = 1900; $year <= $year_limit); $year++)
```

and pass an argument something greater than 2014...